# Function from external:404 Not Found

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

[W3Schools Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_src)

My **index.html** Code is like,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
<body><button onClick="Test()">test</button></body>
```

My **function.js** file,

```
function Test(){
alert ("Success");
}
```

There is file in that directory but console says 404 not Found

Comment: I think your problem is some thing related to path. `/function.js`

Comment: Have you looked at your browser's error console to see why? Your code has no errors, so the script probably fails to load.

Comment: Alright  it  says 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code it's working fine. If you are getting 404 not found error it means  there is only issue in your function.js file path

Comment: My Directories look like :-
views/index.ejs
views/function.js

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative path

> ./function.js